# After Tranfer to New Domain all Links redirect to Old Domain

Tags: domain, redirection

I have magento store on `penhouse.co.in` and I transfer it to `penhouse.in`

Also Changed `core_config_data` with `base_url` and deleted cache from `var/cache` directory.

But still the `penhouse.in` redirected to `penhouse.co.in`. 
Please Suggest any Solution.

Comment: Plz let me know version of magento?

Comment: You should change base_link_url

Comment: I am using Magento2 version 2.1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search **value** column of **core_config_data** table for penhouse.co.in if any entry found replace it with new domain penhouse.in and clear all cache.

If this didn't fix the issue then just put an echo and exit statement in index.php file of Magento to verify Magento is getting initiated from domain penhouse.in or not. Might be it is getting redirected before reaching Magento.

Comment: I  found one column which contain penhouse.co.in and I replaced with penhouse.in. Now redirection is not there but it is showing { The page isn’t redirecting properly} site is not loading.

Comment: And I already test domain with test html file It reach to Magento directory

Comment: Please give a check to .htaccess file of Magento in that case.

Comment: What to change in .htaccess ?

Comment: whether it contains any redirection rule related to this problem or not.

Comment: Is this issue also contains because of SSL . Current ssl is working for penhouse.co.in

Comment: Might be. Do you have secure URL configured in Magento i.e is it https://penhouse.in/ in core_config_data? If yes, trying changing it to http://penhouse.in/ for confirming whether the issue is due to SSL